# How to get phpmyadmin after 'sudo apt-get install lampp-server^

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, phpmyadmin, lampp

I am a newbie in linux programming. I just install lamp server using the command `sudo apt-get install lampp-server^`
Now the problem is that when i place my website files in `/var/www/html` folder, it displays the webpages but i need phpmyadmin to create the database. Does the above command not install `phpmyadmin` or do i need to manually install it myself?

Thanks for any help..

Answer (score 1):

Do this

```
 sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

This will install phpmyadmin. Once installed run the following command

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -plow phpmyadmin
```

A wizard should appear, select Apache2 from the list (you need to hit spacebar to select). And then restart apache and check again.

You can check [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/268167/how-to-access-phpmyadmin-in-lamp) for details.